# How can I jump to ViewController from TabBarController on AppDelegate - handleWatchKitExtensionRequest?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, watchkit

My initial view controller is a uitabbar controller. I call **handleWatchKitExtensionRequest** in my app delegate from the WatchKit app and from there I want to direct jump (by example) to the 3rd tab. I am using:

```
[[((UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController) viewControllers] objectAtIndex:2];
```

The destination view controller is direct connected to the 3rd tab at the tabbar controller (without a navigation controller). But nothing happens?

Comment: The code you show returns a reference to a controller in the 3rd tab, but that doesn't do anything to select it (nor do you assign the result of that statement to anything, so it's useless). I suggest you look at the UITabBarController reference for a more appropriate method.

Comment: can you please give me an example how the call should be to work properly?

Comment: I got it, thanks your help:

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
            tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;

Comment: Take a look at the description of the selectedViewController property in the UITabBarController docs. The "**Discussion**" section tells you exactly what you need to know.